# $T(n) = T(n/2) + T(2n/3) + T(3n/4) + n$ Solve for n

Tags: recurrence-relations

How do I unravel this recurrence relation?

$$T(n) = T(n/2) + T(2n/3) + T(3n/4) + n$$

Here's what I've got so far:
$$= T(n/4) + t(n/3) + T(3n/8) + T(n/3) + T(4n/9) + T(n/2) + T(3n/8) + T(n/2) + T(9n/16) + 35n/12 = T(n/4) + 2T(n/3) + 2T(3n/8) + T(4n/9) + 2T(n/2) + T(9n/16) + 35n/12$$

obviously this isn't the way to go. wut do?

Comment: Is this supposed to hold for all $n$ multiples of $12$? Or for all $n$?

Comment: What initial conditions are you given?  You have $T(12)=T(6)+T(8)+T(9)+12$ but even with those you have trouble with $T(24)$ or $T(144)$

Answer (score 1):

$T(n)=T\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)+T\left(\dfrac{2n}{3}\right)+T\left(\dfrac{3n}{4}\right)+n$

$T(n)-T\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)-T\left(\dfrac{2n}{3}\right)-T\left(\dfrac{3n}{4}\right)=n$

Getting the particular solution part is very easy.

Let $T_p(n)=An$ ,

Then $An-\dfrac{An}{2}-\dfrac{2An}{3}-\dfrac{3An}{4}\equiv n$

$-\dfrac{11An}{12}\equiv n$

$\therefore-\dfrac{11A}{12}=1$

$A=-\dfrac{12}{11}$

$\therefore T_p(n)=-\dfrac{12n}{11}$

But getting the complementary solution part is very difficult.

Since we should handle the equation $T_c(n)-T_c\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)-T_c\left(\dfrac{2n}{3}\right)-T_c\left(\dfrac{3n}{4}\right)=0$ .